# Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r

Was trying to filter numeric value >100 to create a new vector , but am getting the error. tried upload dplyr package & removing as.numeric with no luck . any help much appreciated.

> c1<-c(1000,200)
> class(c1)
> [1] "numeric"
> outies<-c1%>%filter(c1>as.numeric(100))
> Error in UseMethod("filter_") :
> no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: `filter` is for filtering data.frames. It does not work with vectors. Maybe you want `data.frame(c1 = c(1000,200) ) %>% filter(c1 > 100)`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @stefan, the `filter()` function in `dplyr` is used for filtering data frames and not vectors. @stefan's suggestion is to put your vector in a data frame (as one column) and then use the `filter()` function on it.

In case you absolutely need to keep your data in a vector and you would also like to use the tidyverse style of coding (i.e. with the pipe operator `%>%`), you could use the `keep` function inside the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)

c1 <- c(1000, 200)
 
keep(c1,  ~ .x > 100) # both values in the vector are greater than 100
[1] 1000  200
```

After all this, my personal opinion is that base R is more appropriate for filtering vectors:

```
c1[c1 > 100]
[1] 1000  200
```

Comment: Thanks alot for providing different options.